# How do I apply Javascript functions to multiple instances of a class?

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that is displaying a set of images using a table for simple layout. What I'd like to do is allow a user to click the image and have that image appear magnified in a modal.

The html row holding a graphic:

```
<tr>
    <td>Graphic One</td>
    <td><img class="graph" src="/chart1.jpg">
        <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-btn">&times;</span>
                <img src="/chart1.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is repeated to create more rows with graphics. Here's the script:

```
<script>
let modalBtn = document.querySelector(".graph")
let modal = document.querySelector(".modal")
let closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close-btn")
    modalBtn.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block"
    }
closeBtn.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "none"
    }
    window.onclick = function(e){
    if(e.target == modal){
        modal.style.display = "none"
    }
}
</script>
```

This only seems to activate the first graphic on the page, though, so I'm assuming that the querySelector() stops at the first instance found.

How can I apply this to every row with an image in the table?

Comment: `.querySelector()` will return the first matching element. Try using `.querySelectorAll()` to return all matching elements then loop through them as needed. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply it to every table row, all you need is to select all the `<td>` and then iteratively apply the same logic as you have above to the elements found inside it.

To access the individual elements, you can simply use `Element.querySelector()` instead, assuming `Element` refers to the `<td>`. It helps to give this `<td>` element that contains all these elements a class, so you can narrow down the selection, e.g. `<td class="action">`:

```
<tr>
    <td>Graphic One</td>
    <td class="action">
        <img class="graph" src="/chart1.jpg">
        <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-btn">&times;</span>
                <img src="/chart1.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

...then you can do this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.action').forEach(el => {
    let modalBtn = el.querySelector(".graph");
    let modal = el.querySelector(".modal");
    let closeBtn = el.querySelector(".close-btn");

    modalBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
        // Stop click event from bubbling up
        e.stopPropagation();

        modal.style.display = 'block';
    });

    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
        // Stop click event from bubbling up
        e.stopPropagation();

        modal.style.display = 'none';
    });
});

// Listen to click event on the window ONCE, outside the forEach loop
window.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".modal").forEach(el => {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    });
});
```

You can see that I have left out the window click event listener in the for each loop. The reason is that you can simply rely on `event.stopPropagation` to stop the click event from bubbling to the window object. That means, you simply have to bind the click event *once* on the window.

Also, I would not suggest using `Element.onclick = Function` to add event listeners, because that means you can only assign one handler this way. Use `Element.addEventListener` instead.